# Combine a nested list of tuple with a list in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am wondering whether it is possible to combine a list of tuples with a numpy list in pyspark? I tried to subset the tuple within map, so using rdd.map(lambda x: x[0][0]).collect() but it gave me an error.

This is the example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[("a", 5),("b", 6), ("c", 7), ("d", 8)], np.array([1,2,3,4])])
```

This is my desired output:

```
output = [("a", 5, 1), ("b", 6, 2), ("c", 7, 3), ("d", 8, 4)]
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: If it is really a structure you use (please check the rdd once again) this structure is completely useless in Spark and what you want is not possible in general.

Comment: The entries in an `RDD` tend to be of the same type, I think that's what @zero323 is trying to say, therefore I suggest you to rethink your approach.

Comment: Hmm yeh thats what I thought. Anyway I already found another way to solve my problem thx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you want is this:

```
import numpy as np

rddTup = sc.parallelize([("a", 5),("b", 6), ("c", 7), ("d", 8)])
rddNp = sc.parallelize(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))

combined = rddTup.zip(rddNp).map(lambda (k, v): (k[0], k[1], v))
combined.collect()

# [('a', 5, 1), ('b', 6, 2), ('c', 7, 3), ('d', 8, 4)]
```